# "Иди переоденься". Нужна ли запятая и почему?

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, нужна ли здесь запятая:

— Иди переоденься.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая не нужна. Непросто отвечать на вопросы типа "почему не". Запятая не нужна потому, что нет ни одной причины для ее постановки. Более или менее полный список случаев, в которых ставится запятая, можно найти в [Правилах русской орфографии и пунктуации](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/144-zap).

Возможно у вас есть подозрение, что "иди" и "переоденься" - однородные члены. Но это не так. Речь идет не о двух последовательных действиях (иди, а потом переоденься) а об одном (иди с целью переодеться)

Вот что говорит об этом [справочная служба русского языка](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=277430)

*Не ставится запятая между двумя глаголами в одинаковой форме, указывающими на движение и его цель или образующими единое смысловое целое (в таких сочетаниях нет однородных членов): Иди убери мусор*

Comment: не объясните, зачем, давая ссылку на "Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации (1956)", упоминать "Грамоту"?

Comment: @Мимоходов. Исправил, так лучше?

Comment: Да, так лучше. )))

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Да, я засомневалась в последовательности действий, хотя интуитивно запятую не ставила. Захотела себя проверить и точно знать правило. Еще раз спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Сочетание глаголов пойти,взять с другими глаголами(Пойду позову отца. Возьму и продам завтра дом.) - простое глагольное сказуемое,это одно действие, поэтому запятой нет.

Простое глагольное сказуемое может выражаться не только одним глаголом, но и сочетанием глаголов с частицами (Удружил так удружил.Я было пошёл в огород. Он спит себе и ничего не знает. Она так и вскрикнула.), фразеологизмом (Он долго мозолил глаза нам).

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое. Вы очень помогли.